# 1 хост 2 web app - настройка Apache

Tags: apache

Всем привет!
Есть такой вопрос...
Фронт сайта написан на CodeIgniter (PHP фреймворк).
Админки сайта пока нет, но планируется (админки не было, т.к. на фронте редактировался контент админами).
Админку будет писать второй человек, который хочет только Yii 2 (PHP).

Я нисколько не против Yii 2, но сразу бросаться и переписывать фронт на еще не зарелизенный Yii 2 я не хочу, скорее всего сделаю это потом постепенно.

Поэтому вопрос такой - как нужно настроить Apache, чтобы все запросы /adminka шли на Yii2, а остальные - по-умолчанию - на старый DocumentRoot.
У Yii2 путь "DocumentRoot/yii2/web/".

Вешать на отдельный поддомен не хочу, т.к. думаю об одной авторизации и там, и там. Чтобы админ залогинившись на сайте попал в админку без регистрации.

Пример:

Нужно, чтобы запрос `/about` шел на `/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php`.

Нужно, чтобы запрос `/contact` шел на `/folder1/folder2/folder3/index.php`.

Нужно, чтобы все остальные запросы шли на `/folder1/folder2/index.php`

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вопрос некорректен. Поясните что вы хотите сделать. И в чем ваша проблема.

Comment: Поправил вопрос, снабдив его примером. А что конкретно непонятно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю примерно так:

```
Alias /adminka/ "/full/path/to/DocumentRoot/yii2/web/"
<Directory "/full/path/to/DocumentRoot/yii2/web/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Вариант №2

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?adminka(.*)$ /yii/index.php [L,QSA]
```

понятное дело, yii должно быть в DOCROOT

Comment: Именно URL /adminka/ работает.
А если делать URL - /adminka/site/login/ - т.е. другой контроллер и action - все равно контроллер и action берутся по-умолчанию.

Кажется, что нужно использовать что-то вроде

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

где $1 будет указанием того какой контроллер и action выбираем.
Но как это RewriteRule применить к алиасу /adminka/ - подскажете?

Comment: Второй вариант отлично сработал! Спасибо! А как мне закрыть папку yii от просмотра via браузер и разрешить доступ только в /web?

Comment: Options All -Indexes